Shared, public google colab: each user/view should have empty outputs to start with
I have made a google colab that demonstrates a flow using an SDK (the details are not important).
I want to share the link publicly so people can go through the flow and try for themselves.
How can I make sure that when a new user goes to the link, they do not see the output of the previous user. They should see empty outputs so they can go through the flow.
Thanks in advance
